# ¿Pintar y borrar objeto opengl C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

Buenas, edito la duda en opengl en c++

Este son las funciones principales donde se sitúa mi duda (he suprimido codigo de configuracion de camara, luces y buffers de color para simplificar). Las funciones "drawRoom" y "drawMesa" combinan primitivas para formar una habitación cuadrada y una mesa.

Quisiera mostrar una mesa en el caso en el que el usuario teclee "m". Sin embargo, con estas instrucciones, no me pinta la mesa. No sé si es por un mal manejo de la condición de pintado o porque éste no debe ir en la sección de display del programa

```
   void funDisplay() {

    // Borramos el buffer de color
    // Para configurar la matriz matriz P
    // Matriz de Proyección P (Cámara): Perspectiva (gluPerspective
    // Para configurar las matrices M y V
    // Matriz de Vista V (Cámara)

    // Dibujamos la escena(M)
     mesa = false; //Condicion de pintado
     drawRoom();  //Rectangulos contenedores de la escena
     glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
        if(mesa==true){
          drawMesa(); //Funcion que dibuja una mesa en pantalla
        } 
     glPopMatrix();

     // Intercambiamos los buffers
     glutSwapBuffers();
   }

 void teclasNormales(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

   switch (key) {
    case 'm': //tecla m
        mesa = true;
        drawMesa();
        break;
 }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: No entiendo nada de tu pregunta. En OpenGL (y cualquier librería gráfica) los elementos se pintan a cada fotograma, por lo tanto para borrar un objeto tan sólo hay que dejar de pintarlo.

Comment: Si, quizá me he explicado mal. Pero es lo que comentas, poder dejar de pintar un objeto o pintarlo pulsando una tecla. He colocado una condicion booleana que, una vez pulsado el boton derminado, dibuja el objeto, pero no consigo que lo muestre. Si sigo sin explicarme, te muestro un fragmento de codigo

Comment: Hola order666, como regla general, considera cada vez que publiques una pregunta en [es.so] incluir un __[mcve]__. No es un requisito obligatorio, pero te aseguro que te ayudará a ti a crear una buena pregunta y a los demás ayudará a la mejor comprensión de tu problema.

Comment: Edité, añadiendo el código y reformulando la pregunta, a ver si así sirve de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que vas a dibujar la escena estableces `mesa = false` por lo tanto la condición que se encuentra más adelante no se cumple (`mesa==true` o simplemente `mesa`).

En cuanto a la función `teclasNormales`, deberías alternar el valor de `mesa`. Así:

```
mesa = !mesa;
```

Por cierto, no deberías llamar la función `drawMesa` ahí. Probablemente dibujes constantemente la escena así que solo espera hasta el siguiente frame y se dibujará cuando toque con la nueva lógica.